# Returning a value from a stored procedure to a method

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which returns whether a student is locked or not:

```
RETURN @isLocked
```

I execute this stored procedure like:

```
    public int IsStudentLocked(string studentName, int lockoutTime)
    {
        SqlConnection connObj = new SqlConnection();
        connObj.ConnectionString = Util.StudentDataInsert();
        connObj.Open();

        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("uspCheckLockout", connObj);

        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Studentname", studentName));
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LockoutTime", lockoutTime));

        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connObj.Close();

        //How can I return the @isLocked value below?
        return ((int)(@isLocked));

    }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To use the `RETURN` statement in T-SQL (which can ONLY return integer values), you have to add a parameter to retrieve it:

```
public int IsStudentLocked(string studentName, int lockoutTime)
{
    SqlConnection connObj = new SqlConnection();
    connObj.ConnectionString = Util.StudentDataInsert();
    connObj.Open();

    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("uspCheckLockout", connObj);

    comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Studentname", studentName));
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LockoutTime", lockoutTime));

    var returnParam = new SqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "@return",
        Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
    };

    comm.Parameters.Add(returnParam);

    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

    var isLocked = (int)returnParam.Value;
    connObj.Close();

    return isLocked;

}
```

However, this is kinda messy (IMO). Usually what I do in this case is to `SELECT` the value that I want as the last statement in my stored procedure. Then I use `ExecuteScalar` on the command object to retrieve the value instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Proc:

```
... SQL ...

SELECT @isLocked
```

Method:

```
public int IsStudentLocked(string studentName, int lockoutTime)
{
    using(SqlConnection connObj = new SqlConnection())
    {
        connObj.ConnectionString = Util.StudentDataInsert();
        connObj.Open();

        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("uspCheckLockout", connObj);

        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Studentname", studentName));
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LockoutTime", lockoutTime));

        return (int)comm.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I call this "ISStudentLocked" method to a boolean mehtod? something like this:
        public static bool IsLockedOut(string studentName)
        {                 
            return (IsUserLocked(studentName, Util.LockoutDays) == 1);
        }

Comment: I get a "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Student.Models.Authorization.IsStudentLocked(string, int)" error

Comment: Just make the method I supplied static. That's really a whole different issue.

Answer (score 3):

You should call ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteNonQuery and replace RETURN with SELECT in your stored proc.

By the way, you should wrap your connection with `using` block, so it will be properly disposed even in case when some exception occured before Close().

Comment: And then How do I access the return value though?

Comment: It will be returned from this method... ^^'

Comment: The question is specifically about stored procedures `return`ing a value.

Answer (score 0):

If @IsLocked an output parameter in your Stored Procedure

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter paramterIsLockedOut = command1.Parameters.Add("@MyParameter", SqlDbType.SmallInt);
paramterIsLockedOut.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
command1.ExecuteNonQuery();

int newValue = (int)paramterIsLockedOut.Value;
```